# How many nodes?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

How many nodes does this circuit have? I can say that one is between the inductor and the source, the second one between R and C, is there another one bewteen L and R? if the answer is yes, why?

Comment: Where’s ground?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Each 'node' you mentioned has its own current/voltage properties, especially with v changing.

Comment: The Kirchhoff’s law may not be the solution but may shed light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

There are four points in this circuit where voltages are different. They can be referred to as nodes. Whenever we say "voltage" at a point, the reference point is ground of that circuit. Ground is also a node, which is considered to be at zero voltage. Here it would be the -ve terminal of the supply. So there are four nodes in this circuit.

Answer (score 1):

**Node** is the point at which there is a common connection in between two or more elements.

> How many nodes?

One can determine number of nodes in a circuit using this formula:

\$b = l + n - 1\$

Where \$b\$ is number of branches, \$l\$ is number of loops and \$n\$ is number of nodes.

> I can say that one is between the inductor and the source, the second one between R and C, is there another one bewteen L and R

Yes, you are right and plus one more node at ground.

Because at these points voltages are not same. Wherever there is difference in voltage between two points then it can be called as node.

Comment: Rearranging your formula then we get \$ n = b - l +1 \$. All the components can be put on one branch and there is one loop so \$ n = 1 -1 + 1 = 1 \$ node. But there are four. Can you clarify how this works?

Comment: @Transistor Sorry, without calculating I answered. This formula worked all the time when I applied but here it is giving wrong. Can u please tell me, is this formula applicable only if multiple branches/loops are in circuit?

Comment: I have never seen it before - that's why I asked. I don't have any other information.

Comment: @Transistor please, check this https://imgur.com/a/v45tk

Comment: That seems to say that each component is a branch. Then your formula becomes \$ n = b - l + 1 = 4 - 1 + 1 = 4 \$ which would be correct.